# Integration of a slider slide show in an existing html template

Tags: html, css

I am trying to update our wedding page with some pictures of this great day.

In order to test this, I have a slider which is working fine on a dumy page.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightslider.min.css" />
    <!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Mariage de Marie et Laurent</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightslider.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,300,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    
    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    
    <!-- Owl Carousel  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    
    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gallery" style="max-width: 500px;">
      <ul id="lightSlider">
        <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="tlook/TLOOK-001-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="tlook/TLOOK-001-web.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="tlook/TLOOK-002-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="tlook/TLOOK-002-web.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="tlook/TLOOK-003-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="tlook/TLOOK-003-web.png"/></a></li>
      </ul>
      <img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto !important;" id="picture" src="tlook/TLOOK-001-web.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({autoWidth:true, enableDrag:false, pager:false});
      $("#lightSlider img").click( function() {
      $('#picture').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
      $('#picture').attr('alt', $(this).attr('alt'));
      });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After this conclusive test, I was trying to integrate this slider in my existing template that I have downloaded from freehtml5.co.

Unfortunately, I get a "strange" result which no longer displays the pictures of the sliders as they should be, but just one after the other. Additionally, unlike the example above, I am unable to click on the thumbnail pictures in order to display them bigger. I am not quite sure how I can better describe this problem, so I enclose a picture which will hopefully show better the problem.

Due to the size limit of this post, I am not able to copy my css here, I have uploaded my files to my website http://laurentmarie.info/demo

Can you please give me some hints on how to solve this problem?

Many thanks for your kind help.

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Mariage de Marie et Laurent</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightslider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightslider.min.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,300,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento" rel="stylesheet">   
<!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- Magnific Popup -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<!-- Owl Carousel  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">    
<!-- Theme style  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">        
<!-- Modernizr JS -->
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- FOR IE9 below -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    
</head>
<body>
<div class="fh5co-loader"></div>    
<div id="page">
<nav class="fh5co-nav" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
<div id="fh5co-logo">Bienvenue</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-10 text-right menu-1">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Page d'accueil</a></li>
<li><a href="liste_mariage.html">Liste de mariage</a></li>
<li><a href="story.html">Our story</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="gallery.html">Galerie</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>    
<header id="fh5co-header" class="fh5co-cover" role="banner" style="background-image:url(images/img_bg_2.jpg);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
<div class="display-t">
<div class="display-tc animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
<h1>Marie &amp; Laurent</h1>
<h2>Just married</h2>
<img src="images/colmar.png" alt="Colmar, 2019"></img>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>    
<div id="fh5co-couple" class="fh5co-section-gray">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center fh5co-heading animate-box">
<h2>Hello!</h2>
<h3>Ce samedi 18 juillet</h3>
<p>Vous avez c&eacute;l&eacute;br&eacute; ce jour magique &agrave; nos c&ocirc;t&eacute;s ou en pens&eacute;es</p>
<p>Venez jouer les prolongations en visitant la galerie ci-dessous...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>    
<div id="fh5co-couple" class="fh5co-section-gray">    
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center fh5co-heading animate-box">
<span>Our Memories</span>
<h2>Notre galerie</h2>
<p>De quoi vivre ou revivre cette magnifique, fabuleuse et magique journ&eacute;e !</p>
<div id="gallery" style="max-width: 500px;">
<ul id="lightSlider">
<li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="tlook/TLOOK-001-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="tlook/TLOOK-001-web.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="tlook/TLOOK-002-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="tlook/TLOOK-002-web.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#lightSlider"><img src="tlook/TLOOK-003-web-tn.png" alt="" data-src="tlook/TLOOK-003-web.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
<img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto !important;" id="picture" src="tlook/TLOOK-001-web.png" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="gototop js-top">
<a href="#" class="js-gotop"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
</div>    
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Easing -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Waypoints -->
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<!-- Carousel -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- countTo -->
<script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>    
<!-- Stellar -->
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<!-- Magnific Popup -->
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>    
<!-- Main -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#lightSlider").lightSlider({autoWidth:true, enableDrag:false, pager:false});
$("#lightSlider img").click( function() {
$('#picture').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
$('#picture').attr('alt', $(this).attr('alt'));
});
});
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: you want images to be horizontal align rather than vertical align. In horizontal align , if more images then a scroll bar appear to slide to check more images ?

Comment: Are you missing lightSlider js as i can see in console some issue?

Comment: @deepak, that's indeed what I'm trying to achieve. And the <script src="js/lightslider.min.js"></script> is also in my code (at the begining of my html page). Thank you for your help.

Comment: why are you loading jquery file 2 time . One is in head other one at bottom.

Comment: Bring your lighSlider.min.js at bottom. It should be loaded after jquery.min.js. Try to place like this.